# Get current directory of last tmux pane

Tags: scripting, tmux

I'm looking for a `tmux` command to obtain the current directory (`#{pane_current_path}`) of the last focused pane, that doesn't require switching to it and switching back.

The following works:

```bash
tmux last-pane
echo "$(tmux display-message -pF "#{pane_current_path}")"
tmux last-pane
```

however I was wondering if there is a way to do this without having to call `tmux last-pane` twice (perhaps a variable that contains the ID of the last pane?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tmux`'s `display-message` sub command with `-t` (target-pane)<sup>[1](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/tmux/tmux.1.en.html#Token%7E2)</sup> flag. For example you can run

```
tmux display-message -p -t ! "#{pane_current_path}"
```

will show details of last pane.

---

<sup>1. [https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/tmux/tmux.1.en.html#Token~2](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/tmux/tmux.1.en.html#Token%7E2)</sup>